# Mysql update table with join, groupby and having caluse

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have problem with the update joined table. I did successful select out the expected result already but I always getting the error when I try to update.

Select query

```
select sale_id, price,cONVERT(sum(price) , decimal(10,2)) as average, s.total from sale_items i
JOIN sales s ON s.id = i.sale_id
where s.currency = 'USD' 
and s.currency_total != 0 
and s.`deleted_at` is null
and i.`deleted_at` is null
group by s.id
having s.total <> average;
```

Update query I tried

```
    UPDATE sale_items i
JOIN sales s ON s.id = i.sale_id

SET i.price=(i.price / (s.total/s.currency_total)), i.total=(i.total / (s.total/s.currency_total)), i.total_tax=(i.total_tax / (s.total/s.currency_total))
where s.currency = 'USD' 
and s.currency_total != 0 
and s.`deleted_at` is null
and i.`deleted_at` is null
group by s.id
having s.total <> average;
```

Error: syntax to use near 'group by s.id having s.total <> average'

Comment: to askl the obvious, what is the error when you update? What MySQL version?

Comment: @danblack Hi, I updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 5.6, per the manual page for [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html), multi table updates have limits including no `ORDER BY`

The `average` only exists in your `SELECT` query, it isn't defined in the update query.

You'll need to include a subquery extending your where like:

```
UPDATE sale_items i
JOIN sales s ON s.id = i.sale_id
SET i.price=(i.price / (s.total/s.currency_total)), i.total=(i.total / (s.total/s.currency_total)), i.total_tax=(i.total_tax / (s.total/s.currency_total))
where s.currency = 'USD' 
and s.currency_total != 0 
and s.`deleted_at` is null
and i.`deleted_at` is null
and s.total <> (select sum(price) from sale_items WHERE sale_id = s.id AND ...)`
```